# Socket.io cross domain issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, apache, sockets

I have a front end angularJS application(client) working in apache server and its API calls are send to a backend application(server) running in NodeJS. Now I want to have a socket connection between the client and the server.
I am using cors npm module for cross domain issue but its not working.

I have seen several solutions regarding this but none of them are working for me.

Here is my server side code:

```
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express();
var http = require('http');

app.use(cors({
origin: true,
credentials: true
}));


var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket) 
{
console.log(":::::::::::::::::::::SOCKET:::::::::::::::::::::")

socket.on('message', function(data) {
    console.log(data); })
});
```

The server is working at http://localhost:8000/

Here is my client side code:

```
function socket() {
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000/');
  return {
     on: function(eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, callback);
     },
     emit: function(eventName, data) {
        socket.emit(eventName, data);
     },
     getSocket: function() {
        return socket;
     },
     removeAllListeners: function() {
        socket.removeAllListeners();
     }
  };
  }
```

I created the above factory in angularJS and called it inside a function as shown below:

```
var socket=PermitFactory.socket();
socket.emit('message', 'ssss');
```

The error I get in the browser console is:

socket-io.js:4948 GET http://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LhvWuIr 404 (Not Found)

And in the server console:

GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LhvUygM 404 18.881 ms - 1153

Please Help!!!

Comment: did your error say anything about CORS  in the console ??

Comment: No. The only error in backend console is ==>GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LhvhEJB 404 3.971 ms - 1153

Answer (score 1):

you are getting `404 (Not Found)` this means the problem is in your url not cors .

`http://localhost:8000/` is the server up ?? the socket server .. if so then `wss` and `ws` before the  `wss://localhost:8000/` or `wss://localhost:8000/`

Comment: Yes the server is up. I tried replacing http with wss.. But not working

Comment: you are getting 404 that means url is not available .. socket server is not enabled or something

Answer (score 0):

Allow Cross domain on your **server side scripting**, put it on app.js

```
//Access-Control-Allow-Origin
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",true);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST,GET,OPTIONS");
    next();
});

app.use(cors());
```

Plugin for google chrome Allowing cros origin

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: Thank you. But now the issue changed to this==>
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LhvZzwR. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method on your client side this will work.

```
var socket = io('https://localhost:8000/', { transports: ['websocket'] });
```